# Should combined flair match Area51 flair?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair

Here's a screenshot of my Area 51 combination flair (left) compared to my [combo SE flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/776bbf5f921e4db18e30a0dfb4e2acdb.png) (right):

[image: flair comparison]

I understand the rep shown on the two might not always match, but they're over 2K apart.

And the medals don't make sense no matter how I try adding the numbers. For instance, my current silver count is:

```
        SO : 2                     Meta SO: 1
        SU : 2                     Meta SU: 2                
        SF : 1                     Meta SF: 1
 Stack Apps: 1
    English: 1                Meta English: 1
      Apple: 2                  Meta Apple: 1
 Webmasters: 1             Meta Webmasters: 1
Programmers: 1
   Web Apps: 1                     Area 51: 1
```

Is the Area 51 count equal to the sum of the left column; that is, it doesn't include MSO or Area 51 itself? And which ones don't contribute to the combo SE flair?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The major difference was that while Area 51 summed the reputation and badge counts for *all* your associated accounts, SE only included accounts where your reputation is >= 200.

We just changed Area 51 to only include reputation and badge counts for sites where your reputation is >= 200, so that it more closely matches your SE flair. But the two are still slightly different: your Area 51 multi-site flair *always* includes your Area 51 account's reputation and badge count, regardless of whether or not you have over 200 reputation on Area 51. (This way, new A51 users aren't shown with zero reputation.)

When comparing flair on the two sites, bear in mind that your account stats are synced nightly. More than a day's worth of discrepancy might indicate that your accounts aren't correctly associated.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, Flair only includes accounts with rep over 200. However I'm not quite sure what the badge count on Area 51 shows. It probably shows all, but badge count is a bit strange on mine:

Total badges:

- 2 gold
- 18 Silver
- **156** bronze

It doesn't look like meta badges count for anything, but for some reason I have to more bronze badges than I should have displayed on total on Area 51, and 1 silver badge is missing.

As I don't have any silver on the localized meta sites, it looks a bit strange.

[rep http://grab.by/grabs/e9300f9762dd4d4f0dd4c0cba4e36c0c.png](http://grab.by/grabs/e9300f9762dd4d4f0dd4c0cba4e36c0c.png)