# On the combined flair, can we determine the image and name from the same account?

Tags: feature-request, flair, gravatar, display-names

It's a bit confusing when the name and picture do not match. Below is a screenshot of my flair today.

[image: ROYAL FLARE!]

The gravatar is the auto-gen for my email address, which is used on Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, and Area 51; in all 4 sites I have the display name of "ccomet". The display name provided, though, is that which I use on Meta Stack Overflow and on Gaming, where I sport two completely different gravatars.

I did read up on [some of the earlier modifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65695/should-combined-flair-match-area51-flair), so I can guess that the gravatar is drawn from Area 51 specifically while my display name is gotten from my highest reputation account (Meta SO). Could we change it so that we only draw this identity information from one account, rather than divide-and-conquer?

Comment: only you would notice something like this, with your multiple personalities and faces and whatnot. +1.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com).

Comment: Note: User "uɐɯsO uɐɥʇɐN"'s linked to website is gone, searching turns up this URL: https://stackapps.com/questions/847/obsolete-stackimage-generating-images-of-questions-and-users-now-with-globa which leads to a version 2, which is also gone; but at least this is documented on our StackApps website.